# Use the compound angle identity to prove $\sin(90^\circ +A)=\cos A$

Tags: trigonometry

Use the compound angle results to prove

$$\sin(90+A)=\cos A.$$

I know this is rather easy question, but I cant wrap my head around it. So can you please show me how to do it. thanks

Comment: Do you know what the compound angle results are?

Comment: @ChrisEagle  yes, but im rather new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you call "compound angle results" to, but we can prove the claim either by

$$\sin(90+\alpha)=\sin(180-(90+\alpha))=\sin(90-\alpha)=\cos\alpha$$

or by

$$\sin(90+\alpha)=\underbrace{\sin90}_{=1}\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha\underbrace{\cos90}_{=0}=\cos\alpha$$

Comment: this is what is meant by compound angle results:[link](http://www.mathsrevision.net/double-angle-formulae) _italic_ **bold** `code`

Comment: Ok, then it is the second way above, though the first one is more direct, imo.